# Is there a way to embed a Google Doc file in a webpage and display a button to pop it out to Google Docs?

Tags: google-docs

I have built a guide which I want to share with an audience.  We want to use Google Docs to create the guide and embed it in a webpage and display a popout button ( similar the old PDF Viewer) . I noticed that some sites have been able to create a popout button which sits next to the doc which allows you to open the original Google doc.

Is there a clear method to create the embedded doc and have the document show? When I have tried publishing the content - it doesn't seem to give me the option to popout doc into Google docs.

Comment: Hi there @UKDataGeek! I don't have a clear idea of your request, could you please show some examples? This [guide](https://support.google.com/a/users/answer/9308870?hl=en) shows how to publish Workspace files to the web, is that a valid solution for your scenario?

Answer (score 0):

I am writing this answer in order to expand my [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70553702/is-there-a-way-to-embed-a-google-doc-file-in-a-webpage-and-display-a-button-to-p#comment124736318_70553702). The [guide](https://support.google.com/a/users/answer/9308870?hl=en) on my comment describes how to publish a file to the web, so it becomes accessible. Once you do that, you may want to embed it into your webpage. In that case please check this other [guide](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/183965#embed_files) to learn how. Please let me know if you need further help.